# Spivak Problem 18-31 (b)

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Problem Description: 
Evaluate the following limit: 
$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty }{e^{-x^2}\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{x}} e^{t^2}dt}$.

The solution books uses L'Hopital's rule, and does as follows:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{\displaystyle\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{x}} e^{t^2}dt}{e^{x^2}}$
$=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{e^{{(x+\frac{1}{x})}^2} - e^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}}$.

My concern is that shouldn't it be 
$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{\displaystyle\int_{x}^{x+\frac{1}{x}} e^{t^2}dt}{e^{x^2}}$
$=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty }\frac{e^{(x+\frac{1}{x})^2)}(1- \frac{1}{x^2}) - e^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}}$.

Comment: Yes: you are correct. Anyway, the factor $(1-1/x^2)$ approaches to $1$, so it can be ignored.

Comment: @Crostul. You are correct about the extra factor, but be very careful in stating that it can be ignored because of approaching $1$. It is not wise to take a limit "half way" on one factor and continue to calculate the limit on the remaining part. The "product of the limits is the limit of the product" does not apply here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The solution is missing such factor arising from the chain rule, and the fact that $(x+x^{-1})'=1-x^{-2}$.